# Basic question about PL/SQL SELECT statement, how to declare

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute the function, but :

> 5/5       PLS-00103:    begin function pragma procedure subtype type
>        current
>   cursor delete.

How can I repair it ?

```
 create or replace function is_valid_value(resourceToCheck in varchar2,columnToCheck in varchar2,valueToCheck in varchar2)
       return varchar2 is 
    v_value valid_values.resourceName%type;

    declare 
     v_resource  resourceToCheck;
     v_name      columnToCheck;
     v_value     valueToCheck  ;

    begin
    begin   
        Select resourceName,columnName,validValue into v_resource,v_name,v_value
        from valid_values
        where
        resourceName =resourceToCheck
        AND columnName = columnToCheck
        AND validvalue = valueToCheck
        AND
        upper(resourceName) =  upper (valuetoCheck);        

    exception 
        when no_data_found then
            return 0;
           end;
        return 1;
end is_valid_value ;
```

Comment: Typo? `begin begin`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have *several* **syntax errors** in the routine:

```
-- function with 3 parameters
create or replace function is_valid_value(resourceToCheck in varchar2,
                                          columnToCheck in varchar2,
                                          valueToCheck in varchar2)
    -- returns varchar2 
    return varchar2 
is 
    -- uses 3 local variables; please, note their types
    v_resource  valid_values.resourceName%type;
    v_name      valid_values.columnName%type;
    v_value     valid_values.validValue%type; 
begin   
    -- if we have a single record
    select resourceName,
           columnName,
           validValue 
      into v_resource,
           v_name,
           v_value
      from valid_values
     where resourceName = resourceToCheck
       and columnName = columnToCheck
       and validvalue = valueToCheck
       and upper(resourceName) = upper(valuetoCheck);        

     -- we return '1' (please, remember the declaration "return varchar2")
     return '1';
exception 
     -- When we have no records
     when no_data_found then
          -- we return '0' (again, we return VarChar2) 
          return '0';
end is_valid_value;
```

Comment: I believe you have covered it all and I have given you a vote up. Just please , if you agree, correct this: 1. v_value     valid_valuesvalidValue%type;  into  v_value     valid_values.validValue%type; (one dot is missing) 2. return '0'; end; -- i believe there is no need for end;

Comment: @VBoka: Thank you! You are quite right: I've made two syntax errors myself

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the query to retrieve values just to indicate if there is a record or not. The following query seems to satisfy the requirement and be much simpler.
This way you avoid an EXCEPTION handler; neither return value is actually an exception so this seems more 'correct'.
I would also suggest using Y/N as the return if you want a VARCHAR2. Use 1/0 if you want to use a NUMBER. Mixing them could be confusing later for maintenance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_valid_value(resourcetocheck   IN VARCHAR2
                                        , columntocheck     IN VARCHAR2
                                        , valuetocheck      IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   func_result  VARCHAR2(1);

BEGIN
   -- Indicate if it is a valid result
   SELECT rec_exist
     INTO func_result
     FROM (SELECT '1' as rec_exist
             FROM valid_values
            WHERE  resourcename = resourcetocheck
              AND  columnname = columntocheck
              AND  validvalue = valuetocheck
              AND  UPPER(resourcename) = UPPER(valuetocheck)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '0' FROM dual)
    WHERE rec_exist = 'Y' OR rownum = 1;

   -- we return '1' (please, remember - VarChar2)
   RETURN func_result;

END is_valid_value;
```

Comment: Don't you have to select INTO func_result?  It's not in the query, so you can't select it by itself.

Comment: @AndyDan - you are of course absolutely correct and I should take more time to re-read before posting. I've, hopefully, fixed that.